# I need to use the DOT language for a python program but I cannot find a way to do it

Tags: python, graphviz, dot

Apologize if you think this question is dumb. I have already spent over two hours trying to understand the example code in the documentation on https://pysimpleautomata.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html. I pasted the example code:

```
digraph{
    s1 }
```

and Pycharm tells me it is invalid syntax. There should be something between "digraph" and "{".

I am very lost. I have searched for Youtube videos and websites but none of them talks about what I should do.

My complete code:

```
import graphviz
from PySimpleAutomata import automata_IO, NFA, DFA
import pydot
digraph {
    s1,
    s2,
    s3,
    s4 }
```

I appreciate it a lot if someone can tell me if I am supposed to write the codes of digraphs in the py file or how to create a dot file. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try digraph={s1,s2,s3,s4}

Comment: According to https://pysimpleautomata.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#usage you can read the DOT code from a file. I guess you can also read it from a string but it can't just be placed in a Python script as you did in your code.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using this specific library? It seems to be focused on other things rather than building diagrams (conversion etc). See https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html for some examples.

Comment: @MichaelButscher , Now I am trying to create a .dot file using a text editor but it is automatically converted to the MS dot file. I am not sure if this is another issue because Pycharm cannot find my dot file.
My code:
dfa_example = automata_IO.dfa_dot_importer('/Users/name/PycharmProjects/Assignment/file name.dot')

Comment: @ayhan I have to use this particular library as it is required by my course. My TA ended up not having any tutorial to explain this assignment...

Comment: Was the .dot file converted or did microsoft just claim that it was a word file? if you edited with a plain text editor like notepad, its likely fine. Graphviz suggests using .gv as an extension because of this problem. https://forum.graphviz.org/t/what-is-the-file-extension-for-dot-file/35.

Comment: I saw the .gv suggestion but then I cannot edit the gv file directly. I have just tried the txt file and it works. My program can finally generate a dot file (that is opened by MS word) and a svg file.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't supposed to use them directly in a Python file. Instead, you should be writing them in a separate text file, and import it with `dfa_dot_importer`:

```
from PySimpleAutomata import DFA, automata_IO

your_dfa = automata_IO.dfa_dot_importer('/path/to/input.dot')
```

Comment: Is it ok if the dot file instantly becomes a MS dot file when I change the file type to dot?

Comment: @blue That's ok. In fact, it doesn't need to have `.dot` extension. As long it was a text file then it's fine.

Comment: Thank you!! My py file can finally detect the txt file.

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to create four nodes s1, s2, s3, s4.
So, Try following code.

```
import graphviz
dot = graphviz.Digraph()
dot.node('s1')
dot.node('s2')
dot.node('s3')
dot.node('s4')
print(dot.source)
```

This is the output

```
digraph {
    s1
    s2
    s3
    s4
}
```

Comment: It seems to work but I think the code is about showing a diagram. I am not sure to be honest because I have never imported any external library at all.

Comment: Can you clarify your objective, so that, more help can be done.

Comment: The program needs to accept a DFA or NFA table from the user and generate a table, as well as convert the DFA to NFA. I thought all/most of the coding part was done in the py file but I was wrong.